# Creating quiver plot from angle data (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
DATE TIME    WINDSPEED DIR   GUSTS
1/27/20 0:00    6.61    56  7.39
1/27/20 1:00    6.61    54  7.58
1/27/20 2:00    6.22    53  7.58
1/27/20 3:00    4.47    82  5.25
1/27/20 4:00    4.47    93  5.25
1/27/20 5:00    3.89    83  4.28
```

And I want to create a plot that looks like this using matplotlib:

[image]

I'm familiar with basic quiver plots using meshgrid and vector X,Y data. However, this data is in angels, so I'm not sure how to approach it.

Any directions?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you simply have to provide the x/y components of the vectors as paramters `U` and `V` to quiver. The origin is given by `X`,`Y`.

```
U = np.cos(df['DIR']*np.pi/180)
V = np.sin(df['DIR']*np.pi/180)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['DATE TIME'], df['GUSTS'], 'r-', label='Gusts')
ax.quiver(df['DATE TIME'], df['WINDSPEED'], U, V, label='Winds')
ax.legend()
```

[image]